# How to install realm studio on linux/Ubuntu?

Tags: realm

I have downloaded **realm-studio-1.20.0-x86_64.AppImage** from [realm studio](https://realm.io/products/realm-studio/). How do I install this image in order to browse encrypted realm
mobile database on my personal machine that is either exported or fetched from emulator or real device.

**Note:** I don't want to use stetho plugin for chrome as it dose not support encrypted realm mobile database browsing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is actually quite easy, all you need to do is set its privilege to be executable:

```
chmod +x realm-studio-1.20.0-x86_64.AppImage
```

And then you can run it now

```
./realm-studio-1.20.0-x86_64.AppImage
```

Comment: Ehhhh... How can I miss the basic concepts of executing a file? Seems like I am  becoming old:-).Thank-you

Comment: what about the next time if i want open from search is it possible? actually I am unable to find from search

Answer (score 0):

For someone how want to access .AppImage file using UI, follow below steps.

1. Make it executable by following Right Click on .AppImage file >> Properties >> Permission Tab >> Check “Allow executing the file as program.
2. Now run the program by double click on .AppImage file.